# Can be a Schmidt Decomposition Written in this Form?

Tags: quantum-information, unitarity, quantum-states

The Schmidt Decomposition of a state $|\Psi_{AB}\rangle = \sum C_{ij}|i_A\rangle |j_B\rangle$ can be written in this form $|\Psi_{AB}\rangle = \sum \lambda_k|k_A\rangle |k_B\rangle$ where $\lambda_k$ are the Schmidt coefficints. I was reading a manuscrip provided online, written by an expert in this field, and he wrote the Schmidt Decomposition of $|\Psi_{AB}\rangle$ in this way:

$|\Psi_{AB}\rangle = (U_A \otimes U_B ) (|\Psi _A\rangle \otimes |\Psi _B\rangle$) where $U_{A,B}$ are unitary matrices.

How can it be written in this way?

Comment: Please link the paper where you see this. In general, an arbitrary state $\vert\psi_{AB}\rangle$ cannot be expressed as claimed.

Comment: only separable states can be written that way. For example, you cannot write $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$ like that